# Pandas how to apply change to the filtered grouped frame?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Prefix' : ['Mr','Mr','Mrs','Col'], 'Sex' : ['male','male','female','male']})

#Filter all elements which only got a single Prefix - rare elements

df.groupby(['Prefix'],as_index=False).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1)
```

How do I modify the original df based on the filter above? 
What I'm trying to do is change rare values such as 'Col' based on the filter above and 'Sex' details into more generic groups such as 'Mr' / 'Mrs'. 
To be more specific when Prefix is a single value in frame I'd like to replace it with Mr/Mrs based on Sex column.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = df.Prefix.value_counts()
df['Prefix'] = df.loc[df.Prefix.isin(s[s==1].index),'Sex'].map({'male':'Mr','female':'Mrs'}).combine_first(df['Prefix'])
```

Output:

```
  Prefix     Sex
0     Mr    male
1     Mr    male
2    Mrs  female
3     Mr    male
```